# Как анализировать и разбирать исходный код?

Tags: python, opensource, reverse-engineering

Появилась острое желание разобраться как устроен внутри проект [CherryPy.](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy)

Поковыряв исходники в редакторе и порисовав схемы, я понял, что проект довольно объемный. И пока изучаешь одно, забываешь другое. Из за этого теряется общая картина. Есть ли какие-то методики исследования исходников и есть ли какой нибудь софт, скажем, для построение схемы архитектуры или построение схемы абстрактных сущностей со связями между ними?

Comment: Исходники хорошо прокомментированы, пробовали из них собрать документацию?

Comment: Инструментов самых разных много существует (архитектуру из исходника, конечно ничто не построит), потому что анализировать и разбирать исходный код приходится всякий раз когда надо исправить баг, добавить новую фичу—иначе говоря это существенная часть того чем программисты занимаются (с тем же успехом можно спросить как программировать). Общий ответ даже в одну книгу не поместится.

Answer (score -1):

Записывайте свою последовательность выполнений действий, изучайте стандарты PEP8 и как можно больше оставляйте комментариев в своем исходном файле!